# change jquery img src on hover makes images move downwards

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, jquery-hover

I have made a div which contains images, each within their own div, linked to different social media websites at the top of my webpage. I am using jquery to change the `img src` on `hover` and then return to the original image. The images are all 24x24px and the container is 24px high. There are still compatibility issues with firefox but I'm not so worried about them at the moment. The problem I'm having is that when I move the mouse over an image, everything changes and changes back perfectly, but the image lowers itself a pixel or two and cuts off at the bottom. The outer two images don't move when I hover, it's just the ones in the middle.

The site can be found here:

http://tfsm.org/flagshiptest/

Comment: Why not just use css for something as simple as this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your images. For example the YouTube one, the "On" state has a small gap on the top. That's happening in your other links too.

[image]

Comment: Took me a while too see that too. but it looks like the right answer. +1

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the waste of time. It had been a long day and I was feeling frustrated.